# Need some help using JFile chooser to read data from a .txt file

Tags: java, arrays, string, jfilechooser

So I am trying to use JFile chooser to read strings in from a .txt file and save them into an array. I though I had this a set up right but the problem is nothing is getting put into the array because when I display the array it is all nulls. I am new to java so I am not that familiar with using JFile chooser. The window pops up and everything and lets me choose a file so I think it is working somewhat. Also if you could explain to me what all of the code mean regarding the JFile chooser I would be very grateful, most of what I have is from videos, online and books and I kind of understand it but I definitely need some further explanation.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; // All My imports
import javax.swing.*;
public class SpellChecker // I am creating a spell checker
 {
  static String check[] = new String[50]; // My array to save all of the strings in a file
  static int index = 0; // index will incremented whenever a string is added to the array
public static void main(String args[])
{
    getFile(); // Method call that opens file and saves all the data to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < check.length - 1; i++) // outputting the array 
    {
        System.out.println(check[i]);
    }   
}
public static void getFile()
{
    JFileChooser chooser; 
    File infile, directory;
    int status;
    String wordToCheck;
    chooser = new JFileChooser( );
    status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        infile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        directory = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
        try
        {
            infile = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(infile);
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                wordToCheck = scanner.next();
                if(index == check.length)
                {
                    String tempAr[] = new String[check.length*2];
                    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                    {
                        tempAr[i] = check[i];
                    }   
                    check = tempAr; 
                }
                check[index] = wordToCheck;
                index++;
            }
            scanner.close();
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Open File dialog canceled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to get a debugger and find out what's wrong. Also, why set `inFile` twice? Once should be plenty. Also, note that your problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with use of a JFileChooser.

Comment: Honestly Idk. I am going off what I have seen in books and online. I am not good with JFile choose and I am weak with file I/O in general But I am trying to learn and get better at it.

Comment: I ran a debugger using Eclipse and It worked so i'm not sure what that means